# htaccess mod_rewrite & apache2 not rewriting forward slash

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

In my .htaccess file, a mod_rewrite that I use works on some Apache 2 servers but not on others. For example, this rewrite works on all Apache2 servers:

```
RewriteRule ^index-stormwatch.html$ index.php?action=stormwatch
```

But when I replace the hyphen with a forward slash in the mod_rewrite like below...

```
RewriteRule ^index/stormwatch.html$ index.php?action=stormwatch
```

...some Apache 2 servers will give me a 404 error (but not all). Is my mod_rewrite improperly written or do I need to edit the httpd.conf file (or another file) so that the forward slash '/' will be accepted by apache? All mentioned servers are Apache 2/php5.

Answer (score 1):

Can you like this:

```
RewriteRule ^index/stormwatch\.html$ /index.php?action=stormwatch [NC,L,QSA]
```

That should take care of URI `/index/stormwatch.html`

Comment: Thank you anubhava for your assistance and your code. Unfortunately, one of the Apache2 servers (possibly others) that I work with still does not like the forward slash '/' even when using your improved code. It gladly rewrites the hyphen '-' but not the forward slash '/'. I think that something in the Apache config file(s) may be causing the problem. Thanks again for your assistance. Much appreciated.

Comment: You are most welcome. Please enable RewriteLog in apache config and then see what it spits out for this case.

Comment: I enabled RewriteLog for a few minutes. Created a log with the offending url and notice 4 different 'actions': 1.add path info postfix 2.strip per-dir prefix 3.applying pattern 4.pass through. This was my first attempt at creating and reading a log file. May take some time until I fully understand each action. strip per-dir prefix sounds like something that should not happen. Anyway, thank you anubhava for teaching me about the RewriteLog file. I will continue to study until I have a good understanding of Rewrite logs.

Comment: You're most welcome. May I suggest one way of developing understanding of RewriteLog. Generate logs for one working rule and compare that with the non-working one.

Comment: That sounds like very good advice. Thank you for teaching me.